# Disable Add icon to home screen on HTC U11+ running Android 8

Tags: google-play-store, htc, htc-sense, 8.0-oreo

I couldn't figure out where the setting to stop adding icon to home screen when install any app. There is used to be a setting in Play Store under Play Store->Settings->Add icon to home screen.

I have no problem to disable that on my HTC M9+ (Android 5.0.2) and Mi 5S Plus(Android 7). All 3 phones are running the same version of Play Store, 8.4.19.V-all[0][FP]175058788

This article described the setting does not apply to HTC U11+ as it is running Sense as home screen management/launcher, so the Home setting is replaced by Sense Home settings, and there is no such configuration within the setting to disable adding icon to home screen.
[How do you disable "add icon to home screen" on Android Oreo?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/182782/how-do-you-disable-add-icon-to-home-screen-on-android-oreo)

Anyone has any suggestions? Thanks in advance.